# sending multidimensional JSON data via PHP cURL

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, php-curl

I'm developing an http client and choose php curl extension to make http request.
Api needs **multidimensional json** as parameter.

```
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonData))
    );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

when I use this snippet as single script file and try in php cli it works but in laravel it is not working. I get an error "Maximum execution time of 60 secods exceeded."

When I look stackoverflow most examples use single dimensional **json** objects,

- Is there any restriction in php curl settings about json dimensions ?
- When I search the error that I mentioned above is related to "max_input_time = 60" but when I change this to 120 or higher error message didn't changed.
- I'm using **laravel** framework and does laravel have any configuration related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `http_build_query()` instead of `json_encode()`?

As far as I know there are no restrictions about json dimensions on php curl.
I've never worked with laravel though

Comment: when I try http_build_query() I get message "string(41) "Unparsable argument: 2016-03-17 12:11:42" from var_dump

Answer (score 0):

You can override the PHP time limit by using the function below placed within your PHP script.

```
set_time_limit(int $seconds);
```

This should overcome the problem of the request timing out after 60 seconds, however, I would question why the request is taking so long to begin with.

In order to test API's I normally use Google Chrome and Advanced REST client addon, this enables requests to be crafted and saved on the browser. There isn't no restriction on the JSON in terms of multi-dimensions, as I've used several layers deep in the past.

My understanding is that the POSTFIELDS is expecting an array therefore you could amend your request to POSTFIELDS to :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.$jsonData);
```

For Other functions refer [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: When i send same request from js it tooks 1 second to getting response, more then 60 sec is problem that I faced

in js I'm adding "content-type:application/json" header and send json is it wrong in php? Should parameters  be in urlencoded format a=b&c=d

Comment: The fact that it takes only a second in JS but times out from PHP using Laravel suggests that it is hitting some sort of never ending loop. I would suspect raising the limit to even 2 minutes would see it time out yet again. Try putting the JSON data as 'data='.urlencode($jsonData) and see what that does.